# openerp treeview onclick record

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need to enter earnings of employees, employee wise by click them from my tree view (tree shows workers relevant to above selected division.)after their worked hours/total kgs & over kgs enters then form allows to enter wages,incentives,overtime & other things

so need to add that form below section of my form.(not as a popup window)

currently employees' worked hours/total kgs & over kgs saved in a table & wages,incentives,overtime & other things saved in another table.both have worker_id column for identify workers.
please advice me to implement this in openerp ver 7

[refer this link for my form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GiMc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check on your field 'selected_tea_workers_line_ids' you have used editable='bottom'

remove it then it open form view

Comment: yes friend.it load as a pop up form.i need to load inside my page below section

Comment: It possible in old version 6.0. Now it is not possible in 7.0 friend. You have to change in server and web side of openerp if you want that functionality